# Use json_encode() for JSON representation of a value in php file

Tags: php, json, fine-uploader

I need help to properly use json_encode() to return a JSON representation of a value in my php server script. As far as i learned, this is not done with echo, print or loop as explained in all the other questions i studied before asking.

How do i get one "Value" from my data.json file

```
    {
    "clientPrivateKey": {
      "Name":"AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY",
      "Value":"someexammplestring"
      },
    "serverPublicKey": {
      "Name":"AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY",
      "Value":"someexammplestring"
      },
    "serverPrivateKey": {
      "Name":"AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY",
      "Value":"someexammplestring"
      },
    "expectedBucketName": {
      "Name":"S3_BUCKET_NAME",
      "Value":"someexammplestring"
      }
    }
```

into the corresponding PHP variable in my php server script?

```
    $clientPrivateKey =
    $serverPublicKey =
    $serverPrivateKey =
    $expectedBucketName =
```

I only need the "Value" string here. The value is supposed to give a valid JSON response inside the php server script calculating signatures or else it will {"invalid":true}. Thanx for your help!

Comment: Seems like you are on the right track - but instead of using `json_encode` on the contents of your `data.json` file, I think you should instead be using the http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php `json_decode` function which will allow you to access the contents of the json directly as an array or object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the data from a JSON file, you use `json_decode()`, not `json_encode()`. Then you access the parts of it using normal PHP object syntax.

```
$json = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($json);
$clientPrivateKey = $data->clientPrivateKey->Value;
$serverPublicKey = $data->serverPublicKey->Value;
$serverPrivateKey = $data->serverPrivateKey->Value;
$expectedBucketName = $data->expectedBucketName->Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You need to decode your JSON to make it usable:

```
$json = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Note the second parameter set to 'true', it means that we want an associative array instead of an object.

**2.** You can now use your JSON as a regular associative array:

```
$clientPrivateKey = $json['clientPrivateKey']['Value'];
```

You can access the two others values you want by following the previous example.
If you want to know if the offset is valid you can use the *isset()* function on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_decode()` like so:

```
$json = json_decode({
"clientPrivateKey": {
    "Name":"AWS_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY",
    "Value":"someexammplestring"
},
"serverPublicKey": {
    "Name":"AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY",
    "Value":"someexammplestring"
},
"serverPrivateKey": {
    "Name":"AWS_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY",
    "Value":"someexammplestring"
},
"expectedBucketName": {
    "Name":"S3_BUCKET_NAME",
    "Value":"someexammplestring"
}
},true);

$clientPrivateKey = $json['clientPrivateKey']['Value'];
$serverPublicKey = $json['serverPublicKey']['Value'];
$serverPrivateKey = $json['serverPrivateKey']['Value'];
$expectedBucketName = $json['expectedBucketName']['Value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'));
$clientPrivateKey = $json->clientPrivateKey->Value;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner to code to automatically extract the variables from an array:

```
 extract(array_combine(array_keys($array=json_decode($json,true)),array_column($array,"Value")));
// $clientPrivateKey,$serverPublicKey,$serverPrivateKey,$expectedBucketName are now set
```

Example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f1de6493c35cadd0976532b36a23c2fb09bc7b2

Comment: Extract is dangerous unless you're very sure of the data source, since it can clobber arbitrary variables.